# Looking for a share/fraction field

Tags: entities, organic-groups

Following use-case:

An airplane is bought by an (organic) group. Each member has its own share which is dependent on the amount of money chipped in.

All group members together own the plane 100%.

The amount of time a member can use the plane depends on the share he has on the plane.

I was thinking about a share or fraction type of field to link the group member to the airplane.

Any thoughts how to handle the above use-case?

Comment: Considered simply 'amount' field and [computed field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module?

Comment: Looks like a good direction. I will look into the [computed field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module

Comment: If the share will always be equal, it looks like this would be a field on the organic group node, rather than on the user.